# Only keep rows where at least one of the 3 columns equals a given value

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I have a dataframe in which I want to filter to rows where at least one of 3 different columns has value "D"

Sample df:

| identifier | def | abc | ghi |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | D | C | A |
| 2 | A | D | D |
| 3 | B | C | A |
| 4 | A | D | A |

I want my output to be:

| identifier | def | abc | ghi |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | D | C | A |
| 2 | A | D | D |
| 4 | A | D | A |

I would like to use dplyr filter() but couldn't find how to filter to exactly what I need

Answer (score 1):

With `if_any`:

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  filter(if_any(-identifier, ~ .x == "D"))

  identifier def abc ghi
1          1   D   C   A
2          2   A   D   D
3          4   A   D   A
```

Comment: Just select the columns: `if_any(c(def, abc, ghi), ~ .x == "D")`

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R`

```
subset(df1,  rowSums(df1[-1] == "D") > 0)
```

-output

```
   identifier def abc ghi
1          1   D   C   A
2          2   A   D   D
4          4   A   D   A
```